# PMF of X: Number of trials to draw a chip

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let a bowl contain 10 chips of the same size and shape. One and only one
of these chips is red. Continue to draw chips from the bowl, one at a time and at
random and without replacement, until the red chip is drawn.
**Find the pmf of X, the number of trials needed to draw the red chip.**

I thought about using the Bernoulli trial equation but I think that may be wrong to apply here. This problem is just confusing me and I'm not sure how to set a pmf like this us.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: *Continue to draw chips* even after the red chip is drawn. This produces a uniform random ordering of the chips hence, by symmetry, the position $X$ of the red chip in the whole sample is uniformly distributed, that is, $P(X=k)$ does not depend on $k$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks @Did i appreciate your help. I'm assuming that P(X<= 4) = .1+.1+.1+.1 = .4?

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the chips all have student numbers, to make them distinct. Since all orderings of the chips are equally likely, it is equally likely that the red chip is first, second, third, and so on.

So $\Pr(X=k)=\frac{1}{10}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,10$.